# GenericSignatureFormatError on Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.4 with JDK 1.7?

Tags: jvm, aspectj, ibm-was

I am experiencing the "GenericSignatureFormatError" exception in production runtime occasionally. When things go smoothly, we have following information in log:

```
[11/4/15 15:40:01:354 CST] 0000013b SystemOut     O [RequestId:240c17e6-b8a5-4c55-a6ff-f923df9fcd11] c.f.s.w.s.SDKControllerAspect[50] incoming request: GET /api/v1/csr/account/0 ? appKey=0
[11/4/15 15:40:01:355 CST] 0000013b SystemOut     O [RequestId:240c17e6-b8a5-4c55-a6ff-f923df9fcd11] c.f.s.w.s.SDKControllerAspect[68] invoking method:V1CSRController.showAnyAccount(..), argument[0]:com.fet.sdp.ws.sdk.spec.SDKRqAttrAuthorization@128cb1c0, argument[1]:0
[11/4/15 15:40:01:359 CST] 0000013b SystemOut     O [RequestId:240c17e6-b8a5-4c55-a6ff-f923df9fcd11] c.f.s.s.sdk.sso.AAService[54] Cannot find any SDP_CLIENT_SVC_MAP record at time:'Wed Nov 04 15:40:01 CST 2015', with appkey:'0' and apiId:'101020'
[11/4/15 15:40:01:360 CST] 0000013b SystemOut     O [RequestId:240c17e6-b8a5-4c55-a6ff-f923df9fcd11] c.f.s.w.s.SDKControllerAspect[84] result:failed, returning:{"code":"1010200300","message":"authorize error"}
[11/4/15 15:40:01:361 CST] 0000013b SystemOut     O [RequestId:240c17e6-b8a5-4c55-a6ff-f923df9fcd11] c.f.s.w.i.LogInterceptor[66] sessionId:-none-, duration:6ms, path:'GET /api/v1/csr/account/0'
```

However, the request fails from time to time with same input parameters and leaves the following information in log:

```
[11/4/15 15:20:01:530 CST] 000002dc SystemOut     O [RequestId:50922d40-3eaa-49a1-b400-6fc5becbcc20] c.f.s.w.s.SDKControllerAspect[50] incoming request: GET /api/v1/csr/account/0 ? appKey=0
[11/4/15 15:20:01:530 CST] 000002dc SystemOut     O [RequestId:50922d40-3eaa-49a1-b400-6fc5becbcc20] c.f.s.w.i.LogInterceptor[66] sessionId:-none-, duration:1ms, path:'GET /api/v1/csr/account/0'
[11/4/15 15:20:01:531 CST] 000002dc ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause spring: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(SignatureParser.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:311)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSig(SignatureParser.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseParameterAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseParameterAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotations(Method.java:780)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterAnnotations(MethodParameter.java:283)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(MethodParameter.java:301)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(MethodParameter.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.findSessionAttributeArguments(ModelFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    ... 31 more

[11/4/15 15:20:01:532 CST] 000002dc webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[spring]: java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(SignatureParser.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:311)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSig(SignatureParser.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseParameterAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseParameterAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:141)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterAnnotations(Method.java:780)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterAnnotations(MethodParameter.java:283)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(MethodParameter.java:301)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodParameter.hasParameterAnnotation(MethodParameter.java:321)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.findSessionAttributeArguments(ModelFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)
```

This looks very similar to the bug reported few years ago (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=207186), but it is for JDK 1.5.

More environment information is provided as follows:
OS >>
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
Release:        6.6
Codename:       Santiago

WAS & JVM >>
WebSphere [IBMJAVA7 7.0.4.1 gm1318.03]Platform 8.5.5.4 [ND 8.5.5.4 cf041446.03] running with process name xxx\yyy\zzz and process id 21955
Host Operating System is Linux, version 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
Java version = 1.7.0, Java Runtime Version = pxa6470sr4fp1ifx-20130423_02 (SR4 FP1+IV38579+IV38399+IV40208), Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM

AspectJ >>
v 1.7.0

Hope someone can give me a hand on this.
Thanks

Comment: Hi James, have you ever fixed this issue?

Comment: we applied this patch on reflection library:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/reflections/issues/159